# Australian Skilled Independent Visa - How can I prove I have been employed in my nominated skilled occupation

Tags: working-visas, australia

I am planning to apply for the Skilled Independent (Subclass 189) visa in the next few years. The Australian immigration page writes that one might get plus points if the applicant has been working in his/her nominated skilled occupation or in an occupation closely related to it.

I have no doubt that if the applicant makes such a statement, he/she has to be able to support it with evidence. My question is - how can this be proven? In my specific case, I don't want my employer to know about my intentions of moving there until it is absolutely necessary. Is there any way of providing evidence of my employment without involving my employer? As a related question, what if I get a new job meanwhile, before applying for the visa? If the only way of proving my employment is to provide papers from my employer then do I have to contact all my previous employers so that the total duration of working in the nominated occupation adds up for the necessary X years?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they need a reference letter from your employer detailing your skills so as to match them with a list of standard skills required for your nominated skilled occupation. If you cannot provide such a letter from the employer, a statutory declaration from your manager on a non-judicial paper is also accepted. Additionally you are required to provide payslips, bank statements, tax statements, employment contracts, etc. to further evidence the employment.

You cannot make these statements yourself. It has to be either your employer stating these in a reference letter on their letter head or your manager/ supervisor as a statutory declaration.

You get points for work experience in your occupation. The more the work experience, the more points you earn. Therefore, you will need this documentation from all your ex-employers/ ex-managers as well (unless you don't want more employment points).

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to @kpatil answer I would like to stress how important it is to have reference letters in required standard...

Below you will find two examples one that got accepted other rejected ...

**Successful:**
[image]

**Failed:**
[image]

I suggest you make forms for each company that look like former example. You then take originals to Australian embassy for notarization.